# Can't boot various Macs from USB, "malformed file" error

Tags: boot, usb, keyboard, virtualbox, mac

I have been given a USB by my university with a bootable version of Ubuntu (I am unsure what version) pre-loaded with a bunch of software I need for robotics.

Several computers successfully booted off it today, and supposedly they successfully ran it on a few macs in the past. Today however we tried it on a few and had no luck getting past the "Malformed File Error, Press any key to continue" at start-up, as the keyboard/mouse (both the inbuilt one and other wired ones) didn't seem to be getting picked up. This occurs at the very first stage of booting, so there are no menus to change.

Note that the computers tested were an mbpr 11,1, a macbook air of some age, and an imac about 12 months old (the imac didn't even show the USB in the boot menu). When inserting the USB into the macOS, the error "the disk you inserted cannot be read on this computer" or something shows up (which i believe all Ubuntu USBs display on macs). I can't tell what the file format is on the USB, but it shouldn't matter?

So far I've only tried booting it through holding option and selecting the little icon (which actually says Windows underneath it). All that happens is the malformed file error shows up then nothing changes. 
I do have VirtualBox installed but it's a bit of a mission to get a VM of a USB I believe. Does anyone have any suggestions? I know I havent got much info but I don't have much